# How to replace unknown amounts of the same characters with REGEX?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use the JavaScript String.replace method to manipulate markdown code. I want to make it so that all headers are uniform, so I need to take a variety of ##, ###, #### etc. combinations and put a space after them.

Therefore - "##" becomes "## " and "####" becomes "#### ", etc.

I am trying to use the global flag:

```
md.replace("/#/g", "# ");
```

This will not account for all of these combinations of hash symbols. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps, `md = md.replace(/#+/g, '$& ');` will work best for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
md = md.replace(/(#+)/g, '$1 ');
```

Where `#+` will match 1 more `#` and group it as `$1` and replacement is just `'$1 '` which will add a space after multiple `#`

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked great! I added the "g" to the end as well to make sure it took care of all instances.

Comment: Yes `g` is needed for multiple (global) replacements.

Answer (score 2):

I will post my suggestion since I also was ready post but withheld at first after seeing some answers:

```
md = md.replace(/#+/g, '$& ');
```

I think this one is better because:

- It uses `g` option and will handle all `###`s inside an input string
- It does not use capturing groups that are unnecessary when we want to replace with the whole matched text (`$&` backreference is actually the whole match). Capturing groups persist captured texts inside a stack, and this might be a bit slower than without them. Here, we just do not need capturing groups, why use them then?

Comment: *I added the "g" to the end as well to make sure it took care of all instances.* - and that is exactly what I suggested in my comment.

Comment: Good use of `$&` -- always forget about that.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
md = md.replace(/([#])([^# ])/g, '$1 $2');
```

`([#])` checks for a `#`, and `([^# ])` checks for anything but a hash or a space. Then adds a space between them. Hence an extra space doesn't get added to the string already of the form `### a`.

Comment: Interesting alternative. Not sure that it really is any more efficient, and it is slightly harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to replace any occurrence of **two or more** consecutive `#` characters:

```
// Two or more # characters
md = md.replace(/(#{2,})/, "$1 ")

// One or more # characters
md = md.replace(/(#+)/, "$1 ")
```

If you want to append a space after a single `#` character as well, you can change the quantifier from `{2,}` to a simple `+`.